# Connection timeout when trying to connect to cosmosDB from azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have setup a Linux VM on azure, on which i have a nodeJS server running. i Have also set up a cosmosDB with mongodb. i can connect to the cosmosdb from my local machine both using nodejs and a mongo-client, however when i try to connect to the cosmosdb with nodjs from the linux VM i get connection timedout.

I am assuming that this has something to do with the firewall, vnet or nsg, but im new to azure so im not sure how to fix it.

I tried adding an exception in the nsg to allow outgoing connection on the 10255 port, but this had no effect. I also tried adding the cosmosdb to the vnet but this had no effect either.

EDIT:
i have created a node application with app that ONLY has this code:

```
var mongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
mongoClient.connect("connectionString", function (err, db) {
  if(err){
    console.log("it did not work: "+err);
  }else{
    console.log("it did work");
      db.close();
  }
});
```

and it runs fine on my local computer but it cannot connect from the azure VM. no difference in the code what so ever

Comment: If your Linux VM and cosmosDB in the same vnet or two different?

Comment: they are on the same vnet

Comment: With your description, you can connect the cosmosDB from your local machine, so I think your cosmosDB should be OK. First, you can check your cosmosDB firewall following this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/firewall-support. Second, you can check if your Linux VM can connect the internet, in other word, if the network flow can go out from the VM.

Comment: the firewall on cosmosdb is configured correctly according to the documentation you linked, so im assuming the problem has to do with the VMs outgoing traffic. So how do i configure this? i tried adding an exception to the nsg with port 10255 but this did not work

Comment: i was able to connect to the mongodb trough mongodb shell in the terminal after ssh-ing to the VM, however the nodeJS connection is still getting timeout

Comment: You can connect from VM using mongodb, so I think it's not the problem of your VM network. And you can connect cosmosDB using nodeJS on local machine, so I suggest you can check all the things about your nodeJS in VM.

Comment: see edit in main post